# What is the best way to update Ruby 2.x on Debian 7?

Tags: debian, ruby, capistrano

In fact, my goal is to install Capistrano. Currently it requires Ruby version 2.x and higher. But Ruby is available [max 1.9.3](https://wiki.debian.org/Ruby#Available_interpreters_in_Debian_7_.28wheezy.29) in Debian 7. So I was faced with dilemma, which is written in the title of my question: What is the best way to update Ruby 2.x on Debian 7?

My experience does not allow me to choose one of those options that are available on the Internet, and some of it simply do not work.

Comment: Do you strictly need to install a system ruby through the package manager?  If not, you might want to take a look at [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) which I found quite straightforward to use, although I didn't test it on Debian 7 specifically. I believe `rbenv` and `rvm` do similar things (search for them)

Comment: @SauceCode that's a great suggestion, and `rbenv` is available for Debian 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, the best way to install Ruby 2 on Debian 7 is actually to upgrade to Debian 8, which comes with Ruby 2.1. Installing Ruby 2 on Debian 7 would have to be done manually, which seems riskier to me (given your level of experience) than upgrading to Debian 8 — and the latter would bring a number of other benefits.